# How to implement Navigation stack like in Youtube and Instagram Apps?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-navigation

I am trying to make an app with Flutter which use Bottom Navigation Bars. I want to keep my previous visited screens in navigation stack as in Youtube and Instagram apps. For example , assume that I have 3 different bottom navigation bars (A,B and C). After clicking on the tabs A, B and C respectively, I want to return to C, B and A respectively.

This is my main goal, but I have a secondary goal If it is possible to implement.

In Instagram and Youtube, If you click tabs in order A -> B -> C -> B -> C (Now you are on tab C) and after that when you started to click back button it returns you to C -> B -> A tabs. Basically, each tab can be placed once in navigation stack. If you visite same tab more than once, previous screen of same tab is deleted from navigation stack.

I am searching the solution for this problem for two days but I couldn't find. I've even tested the [flutter-go app](https://github.com/alibaba/flutter-go) which is made by alibaba developers, when I click to back button app is just closing.

I would appreciate any help for this problem.

Comment: I have the same idea. Have you found a solution? Please share if you have.

Answer (score 0):

`Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/screenB', ModalRoute.withName('/screenA'))`;

try this one on last FragmentC